# Integral triangles and integral medians

Tags: fastest-code, geometry, integer

Consider a triangle *ABC* where each side has integer length (an *integral triangle*). Define a [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_(geometry)) of *ABC* to be a line segment from a vertex to the midpoint of the opposing side. In the figure below, the red line segments represent the medians. Note that any given triangle has three medians.

[image: triangle_medians]

Let *n* be some positive integer. How many non-degenerate integral triangles with each side length less than or equal to *n* have at least one integral median?

#### Challenge

Write a program to compute the number of integral triangles with at least one integral median for a given maximum side length *n*. The order of the side lengths does not matter, i.e. <6,6,5> represents the same triangle as <5,6,6> and should be counted only once. Exclude degenerate triangles such as <1,2,3>.

#### Scoring

The largest *n* for which your program can generate the number of triangles in **60 seconds** on my machine is your score. The program with the highest score wins. My machine is a Sony Vaio SVF14A16CLB, Intel Core i5, 8GB RAM.

#### Examples

Let *T*(*N*) be the program with input *N*.

```
T(1) = 0
T(6) = 1
T(20) = 27
T(22) = 34
```

Note that *T*(1) = *T*(2) = *T*(3) = *T*(4) = *T*(5) = 0 because no combination of integral sides will yield an integral median. However, once we get to 6, we can see that one of the medians of the triangle <5,5,6> is 4, so *T*(6) = 1.

Note also that *T*(22) is the first value at which double-counting becomes an issue: the triangle <16,18,22> has medians 13 and 17 (and 2sqrt(85)).

#### Computing the medians

The medians of a triangle can be calculated by the following formulas:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
Current top score: Sp3000 - 7000 points - C
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25887/discussion-on-question-by-nicolas-siplis-integral-triangles-and-integral-medians).

Answer (score 7):

## C, brute force - n=6080

This is more a baseline than a serious contender, but at least it should get things started.

n=6080 is as high as I got in a minute of runtime on my own machine, which is a MacBook Pro with an Intel Core i5. The result I got for this value is:

> 15041226

The code is purely brute force. It enumerates all the triangles within the size limit, and tests for the condition:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

static inline int isSquare(int v) {
    int s = (int)(sqrtf((float)v) + 0.5f);
    return s * s == v;
}

static inline int isMedian(int v) {
    return v % 4 == 0 && isSquare(v / 4);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int nTri = 0;
    int a, b, c;

    for (c = 1; c <= n; ++c) {
        for (b = (c + 1) / 2; b <= c; ++b) {
            for (a = c - b + 1; a <= b; ++a) {
                if (isMedian(2 * (b * b + c * c) - a * a) ||
                    isMedian(2 * (a * a + c * c) - b * b) ||
                    isMedian(2 * (a * a + b * b) - c * c)) {
                    ++nTri;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", nTri);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the compiler, you can get faster + better round-to-nearest from using `lrintf()` or `(int)roundf()` instead of adding 0.5f and using the default truncation.  Sometimes you need to use `-ffast-math` to get it to compile to a single [`cvtss2si`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTSS2SI.html) instruction, though.  gcc inlines `lrintf()` and `sqrtf` with only `-fno-math-errno`, so you get efficient asm: https://godbolt.org/g/E3hncQ.  (I used `-march=ivybridge` because that's the OP's CPU).  With `-ffast-math`, clang turns the sqrt into a rsqrt + Newton iteration; IDK if that's a win.

Comment: Oops, usually not `roundf`.  Use `(int)nearbyintf()` if `lrintf()` doesn't inline, because it uses the current rounding mode instead of a specific weird one.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37620659/merit-of-inline-asm-rounding-via-putting-float-into-int-variable/37624488#37624488

Answer (score 6):

## C, approx <s>6650</s> 6900

```c
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static inline int is_square(int n) {
    if ((n&2) != 0 || (n&7) == 5 || (n&11) == 8) {
        return 0;
    }
    
    int s = (int) (sqrtf((float) n) + 0.5f);
    return (s*s == n);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    int count = 0;

    for (int a = 1; a <= n; ++a) {
        if (a&1) {
            for (int b = (a+1)/2; b <= a; ++b){
                if (b&1) {
                    for (int c = a-b+2; c <= b; c += 2) {
                        if (is_square((a*a + b*b)/2 - (c*c)/4)) {
                            ++count;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int c = a-b+2; c <= b; c += 2) {
                        if (is_square((a*a + c*c)/2 - (b*b)/4)) {
                            ++count;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            for (int b = (a+1)/2; b <= a; ++b){
                if (b&1) {
                    for (int c = a-b+2; c <= b; c += 2) {
                        if (is_square((b*b + c*c)/2 - (a*a)/4)) {
                            ++count;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    for (int c = a-b+2; c <= b; c += 2) {
                        if (is_square((b*b + c*c)/2 - (a*a)/4) ||
                            is_square((c*c + a*a)/2 - (b*b)/4) ||
                            is_square((a*a + b*b)/2 - (c*c)/4)) {
                            ++count;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", count);
    return 0;
}
```

I don't really use C often, but with the amount of arithmetic going on it seemed like a good choice of language. The core algorithm is brute force like [@RetoKoradi's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/32852/reto-koradi), but with a few simple optimisations. I'm not sure our values are comparable though, because @RetoKoradi's computer seems to be faster than mine.

The major optimisation is bypassing the `% 4` check completely. An integer square `n*n` is either 0 or 1 modulo 4, depending on whether `n` itself is 0 or 1 modulo 2. Thus, we can take a look at all possibilities for `(x, y, z) % 2`:

```
x%2  y%2  z%2    (2*(x*x+y*y) - z*z) % 4
----------------------------------------
 0    0    0              0
 0    0    1              3
 0    1    0              2
 0    1    1              1
 1    0    0              2
 1    0    1              1
 1    1    0              0
 1    1    1              3
```

Conveniently, there are only two cases to consider: `(0, 0, 0)` and `(1, 1, 0)`, which, given the first two sides `a, b`, equates to the third side `c` having parity `a^b`:

```
 a%2   b%2         c%2 must be
 -----------------------------
  0     0               0
  0     1               1
  1     0               1
  1     1               0
```

`a^b` is the same parity as `a-b`, so rather than searching from `c = a-b+1` and going up by 1s, this lets us search from `c = a-b+2` and go up by 2s.

Another optimisation comes from the fact that, for the `(1, 1, 0)` case, we only need to call is_square once since only one permutation works. This is special cased in the code by unrolling the search.

The other optimisation included is simply a quickfail in the `is_square` function.

Compilation was done with `-std=c99 -O3`.

*(Thanks to @RetoKoradi for pointing out that the `0.5` in is_square needed to be `0.5f` to avoid a double conversion taking place.)*

Comment: Very minor, but you may want to use `0.5f` instead of `0.5` in `is_square()`. `0.5` is a constant of type `double`, so the expression will produce a double value when you add `0.5`, including type conversion from `float` to `double` for the other term.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Ah thanks - that was one surprisingly not-minor `f`, actually.

Answer (score 3):

## Felix, unknown

```
fun is_square(v: int) => let s = int$ sqrt$ v.float + 0.5f in s*s == v;
fun is_median(v: int) => v % 4 == 0 and (v/4).is_square;

proc main() {
    n := int$ System::argv 1;
    var ntri = 0;

    for var c in 1 upto n do
        for var b in (c+1)/2 upto c do
            for var a in c - b + 1 upto b do
                if is_median(2*(b*b+c*c)-a*a) or
                   is_median(2*(a*a+c*c)-b*b) or
                   is_median(2*(a*a+b*b)-c*c) do ++ntri; done
            done
        done
    done

    ntri.println;
}

main;
```

Basically a port of the C answer, but it's faster than it, tested with `clang -O3` and `icc -O3`. Felix and Nim are literally the only two languages I know of that can beat C and C++ at benchmarks. I'm working on a parallel version, but it'll be a bit till it's finished, so I decided to post this ahead.

I also put "unknown" because my computer isn't necessarily the fastest on earth...

Command used to build:

```
flx --usage=hyperlight -c --static -o sl0 sl0.flx
```

The generated C++ is pretty interesting to look at:

```
//Input file: /home/ryan/golf/itri/sl0/sl0.flx
//Generated by Felix Version 15.04.03
//Timestamp: 2015/7/16 20:59:42 UTC
//Timestamp: 2015/7/16 15:59:42 (local)
#define FLX_EXTERN_sl0 FLX_EXPORT
#include "sl0.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#define comma ,

//-----------------------------------------
//EMIT USER BODY CODE
using namespace ::flxusr::sl0;

//-----------------------------------------
namespace flxusr { namespace sl0 {

//-----------------------------------------
//DEFINE OFFSET tables for GC
#include "sl0.rtti"
FLX_DEF_THREAD_FRAME
//Thread Frame Constructor
thread_frame_t::thread_frame_t(
) :
  gcp(0),
  shape_list_head(&thread_frame_t_ptr_map)
{}

//-----------------------------------------
//DEFINE FUNCTION CLASS METHODS
#include "sl0.ctors_cpp"
//------------------------------
//C PROC <61624>: _init_
void _init_(FLX_APAR_DECL_ONLY){
  int _i63436_v63436_s;
  int _i63435_v63435_s;
  int s;
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int ntri;
  int n;
      n = static_cast<int>(::std::atoi((::std::string(1<0||1>=PTF argc?"":PTF argv[1])).c_str())); //assign simple
      ntri = 0; //assign simple
      c = 1; //assign simple
    _63421:;
      if(FLX_UNLIKELY((n < c))) goto _63428;
      b = (c + 1 ) / 2 ; //assign simple
    _63422:;
      if(FLX_UNLIKELY((c < b))) goto _63427;
      a = (c - b ) + 1 ; //assign simple
    _63423:;
      if(FLX_UNLIKELY((b < a))) goto _63426;
/*begin match*/
/*match case 1:s*/
      s  = static_cast<int>((::std::sqrt(((static_cast<float>(((2 * (b * b  + (c * c ) )  - (a * a ) ) / 4 ))) + 0.5f ))))/*int.flx: ctor*/; //init
/*begin match*/
/*match case 1:s*/
      _i63435_v63435_s  = static_cast<int>((::std::sqrt(((static_cast<float>(((2 * (a * a  + (c * c ) )  - (b * b ) ) / 4 ))) + 0.5f ))))/*int.flx: ctor*/; //init
/*begin match*/
/*match case 1:s*/
      _i63436_v63436_s  = static_cast<int>((::std::sqrt(((static_cast<float>(((2 * (a * a  + (b * b ) )  - (c * c ) ) / 4 ))) + 0.5f ))))/*int.flx: ctor*/; //init
      if(!((((2 * (b * b  + (c * c ) )  - (a * a ) ) % 4  == 0) && (s * s  == (2 * (b * b  + (c * c ) )  - (a * a ) ) / 4 )  || (((2 * (a * a  + (c * c ) )  - (b * b ) ) % 4  == 0) && (_i63435_v63435_s * _i63435_v63435_s  == (2 * (a * a  + (c * c ) )  - (b * b ) ) / 4 ) ) ) || (((2 * (a * a  + (b * b ) )  - (c * c ) ) % 4  == 0) && (_i63436_v63436_s * _i63436_v63436_s  == (2 * (a * a  + (b * b ) )  - (c * c ) ) / 4 ) ) )) goto _63425;
      {
      int* _tmp63490 = (int*)&ntri;
      ++*_tmp63490;
      }
    _63425:;
      if(FLX_UNLIKELY((a == b))) goto _63426;
      {
      int* _tmp63491 = (int*)&a;
      ++*_tmp63491;
      }
      goto _63423;
    _63426:;
      if(FLX_UNLIKELY((b == c))) goto _63427;
      {
      int* _tmp63492 = (int*)&b;
      ++*_tmp63492;
      }
      goto _63422;
    _63427:;
      if(FLX_UNLIKELY((c == n))) goto _63428;
      {
      int* _tmp63493 = (int*)&c;
      ++*_tmp63493;
      }
      goto _63421;
    _63428:;
      {
      _a12344t_63448 _tmp63494 = ::flx::rtl::strutil::str<int>(ntri) + ::std::string("\n") ;
      ::flx::rtl::ioutil::write(stdout,_tmp63494);
      }
}

//-----------------------------------------
}} // namespace flxusr::sl0
//CREATE STANDARD EXTERNAL INTERFACE
FLX_FRAME_WRAPPERS(::flxusr::sl0,sl0)
FLX_C_START_WRAPPER_PTF(::flxusr::sl0,sl0,_init_)

//-----------------------------------------
//body complete
```

Answer (score 2):

### C# (about 11000?)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PPCG
{
    class PPCG53100
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(args[0]);
            Console.WriteLine(CountOOE(n) + CountEEE(n));
        }

        static int CountOOE(int n)
        {
            // Maps from a^2 + b^2 to (b - a, a + b), which are the exclusive bounds on c.
            IDictionary<int, List<Tuple<int, int>>> pairs = new Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<int, int>>>();

            for (int a = 1; a <= n; a += 2)
            {
                int k = 2 * a * a;
                for (int b = a; b <= n; b += 2, k += 4 * (b - 1))
                {
                    List<Tuple<int, int>> prev;
                    if (!pairs.TryGetValue(k, out prev)) pairs[k] = prev = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
                    prev.Add(Tuple.Create(b - a, a + b));
                }
            }

            int max = 2 * n * n;
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = 1; x <= n >> 1; x++)
            {
                int k = 4 * x * x;
                for (int y = x; y <= n; y++, k += 4 * y - 2)
                {
                    if (k > max) break;
                    List<Tuple<int, int>> ab;
                    if (pairs.TryGetValue(k, out ab))
                    {
                        foreach (var pair in ab)
                        {
                            // Double-counting isn't possible if a, b are odd.
                            if (pair.Item1 < x << 1 && x << 1 < pair.Item2)
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                            if (x != y && y << 1 <= n && pair.Item1 < y << 1 && y << 1 < pair.Item2)
                            {
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return count;
        }

        static int CountEEE(int n)
        {
            // Maps from a^2 + b^2 to (b - a, a + b), which are the exclusive bounds on c.
            IDictionary<int, List<Tuple<int, int>>> pairs = new Dictionary<int, List<Tuple<int, int>>>();

            for (int a = 2; a <= n; a += 2)
            {
                int k = 2 * a * a;
                for (int b = a; b <= n; b += 2, k += 4 * (b - 1))
                {
                    List<Tuple<int, int>> prev;
                    if (!pairs.TryGetValue(k, out prev)) pairs[k] = prev = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
                    prev.Add(Tuple.Create(b - a, a + b));
                }
            }

            // We want to consider m in the range [1, n] and c/2 in the range [1, n/2]
            // But to save dictionary lookups we can scan x in [1, n/2], y in [x, n] and consider both ways round.
            int max = 2 * n * n;
            int count = 0;
            for (int x = 1; x <= n >> 1; x++)
            {
                int k = 4 * x * x;
                for (int y = x; y <= n; y++, k += 4 * y - 2)
                {
                    if (k > max) break;
                    List<Tuple<int, int>> ab;
                    if (pairs.TryGetValue(k, out ab))
                    {
                        foreach (var pair in ab)
                        {
                            // (c1, m1) = (2x, y)
                            // (c2, m2) = (2y, x)

                            int a = (pair.Item2 - pair.Item1) / 2, b = (pair.Item2 + pair.Item1) / 2;
                            int c1 = 2 * x;

                            if (pair.Item1 < c1 && c1 < pair.Item2)
                            {
                                // To deduplicate: the possible sets of integer medians are:
                                //     m_c
                                //     m_a, m_c
                                //     m_b, m_c
                                //     m_a, m_b, m_c
                                // We only want to add if c is (wlog) the shortest edge whose median is integral (or joint integral in case of isosceles triangles).

                                if (c1 <= a) count++;
                                else if (!IsIntegerMedian(b, c1, a))
                                {
                                    if (c1 <= b || !IsIntegerMedian(a, c1, b)) count++;
                                }
                            }

                            int c2 = 2 * y;
                            if (c1 != c2 && c2 <= n && pair.Item1 < c2 && c2 < pair.Item2)
                            {
                                if (c2 <= a) count++;
                                else if (!IsIntegerMedian(b, c2, a))
                                {
                                    if (c2 <= b || !IsIntegerMedian(a, c2, b)) count++;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return count;
        }

        private static bool IsIntegerMedian(int a, int b, int c)
        {
            int m2 = 2 * (a * a + b * b) - c * c;
            int s = (int)(0.5f + Math.Sqrt(m2));
            return ((s & 1) == 0) && (m2 == s * s);
        }
    }
}
```

`n` is taken as a command-line argument.

#### Explanation

We can rewrite \$m = \sqrt{(2a^2 + 2b^2 - c^2) / 4}\$ as \$2a^2 + 2b^2 = 4m^2 + c^2\$, whence it's obvious that \$c^2\$ must be even, and so \$c\$ is even. Let \$c = 2C\$ and we rewrite again as \$a^2 + b^2 = 2(m^2 + C^2)\$. Therefore \$a^2 + b^2\$ must be even, so \$a\$ and \$b\$ must have the same parity.

The equation \$a^2 + b^2 = 2(m^2 + C^2)\$ is the basis for the meet-in-the-middle algorithm employed here.

If \$a\$ and \$b\$ are odd then we have no risk of double-counting, because only one of the three medians can possibly be integral. If all three are even then we need to beware double-counting. Therefore I handle the two cases separately so that the odd-odd-even case can be processed faster than the even-even-even case.

Comment: I can't build Felix on my machine, but my times for `n=5000` are 67 seconds for Reto Koradi's answer, 48 seconds for Sp3000's answer, and 13 seconds for my answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, n=269 in 59 sec

```
isq?(x:PI):Boolean==perfectSquare?(x)

f(a:PI,b:PI,c:PI):Boolean==
    c rem 2=1=>false
    t:=a^2+b^2
    t rem 2=1=>false
    x:=(2*t-c^2)quo 4
    isq?(x)

h(n)==
   cnt:=0  -- a:=a   b:=(a+2*k)  c:=
   r:List List INT:=[]
   for a in 1..n repeat
     ke:=(n-a)quo 2
     for k in 0..ke repeat
         d:=(a+k)^2+k^2 -- (a^2+b^2)/2=(a+k)^2+k^2   m^2+c^2=d
         l:=reduce(min,[sqrt(d*1.), n/2.,a+k-1])
         kc:=floor(l)::INT
         for c in k+1..kc repeat
             if isq?(d-c^2) then
                            bb:=a+2*k; cc:=2*c
                            if bb>cc and f(a,cc,bb) then iterate   -- 2<->3
                            if  a>cc and f(cc,bb,a) then iterate   -- 1<->3
                            cnt:=cnt+1
                            --r:=cons([a,a+2*k,2*c],r)
   r:=cons([cnt],r)
   r
```

If a,b,cx are length of the sides of one triangle of max lenght side n...

We would know that m:=sqrt((2*(a^2+b^2)-cx^2)/4)

```
(1) m^2=(2*(a^2+b^2)-cx^2)/4
```

As Peter Taylor had said, 4|(2*(a^2+b^2)-cx^2) and because 2|2*(a^2+b^2) than 2|cx^2 =>
cx=2*c. So from 1 will be

```
(2) m^2=(a^2+b^2)/2-c^2
```

a, and b has to have the same parity, so we could write b in function of a

```
(3) a:=a   b:=(a+2*k)
```

than we have that

```
(4)(a^2+b^2)/2=(a^2+(a+2*k)^2)/2=(a+k)^2+k^2
```

so the (1) can be rewritten see (2)(3)(4) as:

```
m^2+c^2=(a+k)^2 + k^2=d         a:=a  b:=(a+2*k)  cx:=2*c
```

where

```
a in 1..n  
k in 0..(n-a)/2  
c in k+1..min([sqrt(d*1.), n/2.,a+k-1])
```

results

```
(16) -> h 269
   (16)  [[14951]]
                                                  Type: List List Integer
        Time: 19.22 (IN) + 36.95 (EV) + 0.05 (OT) + 3.62 (GC) = 59.83 sec
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, n=3030 here

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

#define R     return
#define u32 unsigned
#define F        for
#define P     printf

int isq(u32 a)
{u32 y,x,t,i;
 static u32  arr720[]={0,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81,100,121,144,169,196,225,256,289,324,361,400,441,484,529,576,625,676,180,241,304,369,436,505,649,160,409,496,585,340,544,145,601,244,580,481,640,385,265};
 static char barr[724]={0};
 if(barr[0]==0)F(i=0;i<(sizeof arr720)/sizeof(unsigned);++i)
                if(arr720[i]<720) barr[arr720[i]]=1; 
 if(barr[a%720]==0) R 0;
 y=sqrt(a);
 R y*y==a;
}

int f(u32 a, u32 b, u32 c)
{u32 t,x;
 if(c&1)R 0;
 t= a*a+b*b;
 if(t&1)R 0;
 R isq((2*t-c*c)/4);
}

int h(u32 n)
{u32 cnt,a,c,k,ke,kc,d,v,l,aa,bb,cc;

 cnt=0;
 F(a=1;a<=n;++a)
   {ke=(n-a)/2;
    F(k=0;k<=ke;++k)
        {v=a+k;
         d=v*v+k*k;
         l=sqrt(d);
         v=n/2;
         if(l>v)l=v;
         v=a+k-1;
         if(l>v)l=v;
         F(c=k+1;c<=l;++c)
           {if(isq(d-c*c))
                {bb=a+2*k;cc=2*c;
                 if(bb>cc && f(a, cc,bb)) continue;
                 if( a>cc && f(cc,bb, a)) continue;
                 ++cnt;
                 //P("|a=%u b=%u c=%u", a, bb, cc);
                }
           }
        }
   }
 R cnt; 
}

int main(int c, char** a)
{time_t  ti, tf;
 double   d;
 int     ni;
 u32    n,i;

 if(c!=2||a[1]==0){P("uso: questo_programma.exe  arg1\n ove arg1 e\' un numero positivo\n");R 0;}
 ni=atoi(a[1]);
 if(ni<=0){P("Parametro negativo o zero non permesso\n");R 0;}
 n=ni;
 if(n>0xFFFFF){P("Parametro troppo grande non permesso\n"); R 0;}
 F(i=3;i<33;++i)if(i<10||i>21)P("T(%u)=%u|",i, h(i));
 ti=time(0);
 P("\nT(%u)=%u\n", n, h(n));
 tf=time(0);
 d=difftime(tf,ti);
 P("Tempo trascorso = %.2f sec\n", d); 
 R 1;
}
```

results:

```
C:\Users\a\b>prog 3030
T(3)=0|T(4)=0|T(5)=0|T(6)=1|T(7)=1|T(8)=2|T(9)=3|T(22)=34|T(23)=37|T(24)=42|T(25)=
45|T(26)=56|T(27)=59|T(28)=65|T(29)=67|T(30)=74|T(31)=79|T(32)=91|
T(3030)=3321226
Tempo trascorso = 60.00 sec
```

the above code would be the traslation in C of the Axiom answer
(if we not count the isq() function).

My compiler not link a function others use sqrtf()... here there is no sqrt function for float...
Are they sure that sqrtf it is a C standard function?

Comment: [(since C99)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/sqrt)

Answer (score 0):

## APL NARS, n=<s>239</s> 282  in 59 seconds

```
f←{(a b c)←⍵⋄1=2∣c:0⋄t←+/a b*2⋄1=2∣t:0⋄0=1∣√4÷⍨(2×t)-c*2}

∇r←g n;cnt;c;a;k;kc;ke;d;l;bb;cc
    r←⍬⋄cnt←0
    :for a :in 1..n 
       ke←⌊(n-a)÷2
       :for k :in 0..ke
          d←((a+k)*2)+k*2
          kc←⌊⌊/(n÷2),(a+k-1),√d
          →B×⍳kc<k+1  
          :for c :in (k+1)..kc
            →C×⍳∼1e¯9>1∣√d-c*2
               bb←a+2×k⋄cc←2×c
               →C×⍳(bb>cc)∧f a  cc bb
               →C×⍳( a>cc)∧f cc bb  a
               cnt+←1
               ⍝r←r,⊂a bb cc
   C:     :endfor
   B:  :endfor
    :endfor
    r←r,cnt
∇
```

(i traslate the Axiom answer one, in APL) test:

```
  g 282 
16712 
  v←5 6 10 20 30 41
  v,¨g¨v
5 0  6 1  10 4  20 27  30 74  41 166
```

Answer (score 0):

VBA 15,000 in TEN seconds!

I expected much less after these other posts.  On an Intel 7 with 16 GB RAM I get 13-15,000 in TEN seconds.  On a Pentium with 4 GB RAM, I get 5-7,000 in TEN seconds.  The code is below.  Here is the latest result on the Pentium

```
abci= 240, 234, 114, 7367, 147
abci= 240, 235, 125, 7368, 145
abci= 240, 236, 164, 7369, 164
abci= 240, 238, 182, 7370, 221
abci= 240, 239, 31, 7371, 121
```

It got up to a triangle with sides 240, 239, 31 and a medium of 121.  The count of mediums is 7,371.

```
Sub tria()
On Error Resume Next
Dim i As Long, a As Integer, b As Integer, c As Integer, ma As Double, mb As Double, mc As Double, ni As Long, mpr As Long
Dim dtime As Date
dtime = Now
Do While Now < DateAdd("s", 10, dtime)  '100 > DateDiff("ms", dtime, Now) '
    a = a + 1
   ' Debug.Assert a < 23
    b = 1: c = 1
    Do
        ma = 0
        If a < b + c And b < a + c And c < a + b Then
            ma = ((2 * b ^ 2 + 2 * c ^ 2 - a ^ 2) / 4) ^ 0.5
            If ma <> 0 Then ni = i + 1 * -1 * (0 = ma - Fix(ma))
                If ni > i Then
                If ma <> mpr Then
                i = ni
                mpr = ma
                    Debug.Print "abci= " & a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & i & ", " & ma
                    GoTo NextTri  'TO AVOID DOUBLE COUNTING
                End If
            End If
       'End If

        mb = 0
        'If b < a + c Then
            mb = ((2 * a ^ 2 + 2 * c ^ 2 - b ^ 2) / 4) ^ 0.5
            If mb <> 0 Then ni = i + 1 * -1 * (0 = mb - Fix(mb))
            If ni > i Then
            If mb <> mpr Then
                i = ni
                mpr = mb
                Debug.Print "abci= " & a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & i & ", " & mb
                GoTo NextTri  'TO AVOID DOUBLE COUNTING
            End If
            End If
        'End If

        mc = 0
        'IfThen
            mc = ((2 * b ^ 2 + 2 * a ^ 2 - c ^ 2) / 4) ^ 0.5
            If mc <> 0 Then ni = i + 1 * -1 * (0 = mc - Fix(mc))
            If ni > i Then
            If mc <> mpr Then
            i = ni
            mpr = mc
                Debug.Print "abci= " & a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & i & ", " & mc
            End If
            End If
        End If
NextTri:
        Do While c <= b
            'c = c + 1
            ma = 0
            If a < b + c And b < a + c And c < a + b Then

                    ma = ((2 * b ^ 2 + 2 * c ^ 2 - a ^ 2) / 4) ^ 0.5
                    If ma <> 0 Then ni = i + 1 * -1 * (0 = ma - Fix(ma))
                            If ni > i Then
                    If ma <> mpr Then
                        mpr = ma
                i = ni
                    End If
                    Debug.Print "abci= " & a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & i & ", " & ma
                    GoTo NextTri2  'TO AVOID DOUBLE COUNTING
                End If
            'End If

            mb = 0
            'If b < a + c Then
                mb = ((2 * a ^ 2 + 2 * c ^ 2 - b ^ 2) / 4) ^ 0.5
                If mb <> 0 Then ni = i + 1 * -1 * (0 = mb - Fix(mb))
                        If ni > i Then
                If mb <> mpr Then
                mpr = mb
                i = ni
                    Debug.Print "abci= " & a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & i & ", " & mb
                    GoTo NextTri2  'TO AVOID DOUBLE COUNTING
                End If
                End If
            'End If

            mc = 0
            'If c < b + a Then
                    mc = ((2 * b ^ 2 + 2 * a ^ 2 - c ^ 2) / 4) ^ 0.5
                    If mc <> 0 Then ni = i + 1 * -1 * (0 = mc - Fix(mc))
                            If ni > i Then
                    If mc <> mpr Then
                    mpr = mc
                i = ni
                    Debug.Print "abci= " & a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & i & ", " & mc
                    End If
                End If
            End If
       ' Debug.Print "abci= " & a & ", " & b & ", " & c & ", " & i
            c = c + 1
        Loop 'While c <= a
NextTri2:
        b = b + 1
        c = 1
    Loop While b <= a
Loop
Debug.Print i

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## Rust, brute force, 4500

On my computer, the program calculated that the answer at `n=4500` is 7844386, within 60 seconds.

```
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use rayon::prelude::*;

#[inline]
fn is_square(v: i32) -> bool {
    let s = (f32::sqrt(v as f32) + 0.5).floor() as i32;
    s * s == v
}

#[inline]
fn is_median(v: i32) -> bool {
    v % 4 == 0 && is_square(v / 4)
}

#[inline]
fn calculate_triangles(n: i32) -> i32 {
    (1..=n)
        .into_par_iter()
        .map(|c| {
            let mut count = 0;
            for b in (c + 1) / 2..=c {
                for a in (c - b + 1)..=b {
                    if is_median(2 * (b * b + c * c) - a * a)
                        || is_median(2 * (a * a + c * c) - b * b)
                        || is_median(2 * (a * a + b * b) - c * c)
                    {
                        count += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            count
        })
        .sum()
}

fn main() {
    let n: i32 = 4500;
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    let _computation_thread = thread::spawn(move || {
        let n_tri = calculate_triangles(n);
        tx.send(n_tri).unwrap();
    });

    match rx.recv_timeout(Duration::from_secs(60)) {
        Ok(n_tri) => println!("Result: {}", n_tri),
        Err(_) => println!("Timed out after 60 seconds."),
    }

    // The thread will be terminated when the main function ends, regardless of whether it has finished its computation.
}
```